# phpAdmin MySQL server reports high traffic used

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I'm using X10hosting to host a web site, so I can learn. I'm brand new to hosting and creating my own website. As I was looking around my cPanel, I checked out the 'My phpMyAdmin MySQL Status' panel, and I was surprised to see the amount of network traffic and the amount of time the MySQL server has been active.

The thing is, I've not uploaded anything yet. I'm not sure why this MySQL server is even up and running for.

I'd really appreciate some help in understanding why this MySQL server is running and why so much network traffic (378.6 GB) has been used, and where this traffic is coming from and going too. Is it using my broadband bandwidth?

Here is a copy and paste of the status report of my phpAdmin MySQL server status. What does all this mean?

```
Network traffic since startup: 378.6 GiB
This MySQL server has been running for 6 days, 5 hours, 17 minutes and 29 seconds.
It started up on Jun 07, 2017 at 04:01 PM.

Traffic [​IMG] ø per hour
Received 25.2 GiB 172.6 MiB
Sent 353.5 GiB
Total 378.6 GiB 2.5 GiB
Connections ø per hour %
max. concurrent connections 46 --- ---
Failed attempts 3,140 21.03 0.16%
Aborted 978 6.55 0.05%
Total 1,920 k 12.86 k 100.00%
Processes ID User Host Database Command Time Status SQL query[​IMG]
Kill 1920105 nexuoso1 localhost None Sleep 0 --- ---
```

I see it's on my localhost as well.

Comment: This isn't a programming-specific problem and is better asked on some place like [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) though I'd encourage you to do more homework before going there. You may find your hosting provider's support team can shed some light on these things, or they have an FAQ that addresses it. Normally server processess like MySQL are started once and stay up until it's rebooted, which could be years.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

> The thing is, I've not uploaded anything yet. I'm not sure why this MySQL server is even up and running for.

It's most likely not your own dedicated MySQL server you're seeing.
It sounds to me like this is a shared hosting plan? If so, the information that you see is probably the statistics for all websites hosted on the server that is shared among other websites and including yours.

353.5 GiB is alot, and if you just started, this is not your doing.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since this was posted but I found myself in a similar situation here with Bluehost.  I only just started my website and decided to look in phpmyadmin under Status for the server... only to find I have:

Network traffic since startup: 602 GiB
This MySQL server has been running for 4 days, 9 hours, 25 minutes and 1 seconds. It started up on Aug 16, 2019 at 12:53 AM.

Traffic     #   ø per hour
Received    18.5 GiB    180.1 MiB

Sent    583.5 GiB   5.5 GiB

Total   602 GiB 5.7 GiB

Connections #   ø per hour  %

Max. concurrent connections 104 --- ---

Failed attempts 9,605   91.11   0.83%

Aborted 53  0.5 <0.01%

Total   1,156 k 10.97 k 100.00%

Questions since startup: 78,900,682

ø per hour: 747,746

ø per minute: 12,462

ø per second: 208

I messaged their support team and they said this was totally normal "Its just the traffic going to the website"... Which made no sense... considering I haven't told anyone about it and barely even touched SQL code... There's no possible way I've had 78,900,682 Questions asked to the server in just 4 days, and nothing has changed in my database tables...

I only added a single registration form, confirmation, and login form... none of which is actually available unless you know the exact URL's.

I'd be delighted if anyone has an actual explanation as to why the numbers are so high?

Edit: I should mention that I only added the registration and login form about 11 days ago, so the startup time doesn't even align with when I added all the forms and started working in the DB. I also started hosting with them almost a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine from shared hosting if that helps any:

[image]